# Oracle: problems setting up a view to a remote database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

I have some users who can't access a view that references a table on a remote database. The point of setting up the view was to share relevant information to users without them needing direct access to the remote table.

I set up a series of views that references a remote database through a public database link, using something like:

```
create view MYSCHEMA.MYVIEW1 as
select field1, field2
from SOMETABLE@OTHERDB;

create view MYSCHEMA.MYVIEW2 as
select field1, field2
from MYSCHEMA.MYVIEW1;

grant select on MYVIEW2 to ROLE1;
```

When I access either view, there are no issues.

USER1 and USER2 are both in ROLE1.

When USER1, who has access to SOMETABLE@OTHERDB, queries from MYVIEW2, they have no issues.

But when USER2, who does not have access to SOMETABLE@OTHERDB, tries to call MYVIEW2, they get the error message "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist  ORA-02063: preceding line from OTHERDB".

USER2 confirms they can see MYVIEW2 in the view list in SQL Developer, but the Data tab is empty. USER2 does have an account on OTHERDB, but they do not have select privileges on SOMETABLE.

Both databases are Oracle 19c. There are multiple other instances of views working across this public dblink, but this is the only one in MYSCHEMA.

Is there something I'm missing when setting up these views? Obviously this is a simplified example and the real views are doing more manipulation and linking of tables (not using the OTHERDB database link), but the fact that some users can see the data and others can't is what really confuses me. I can't find anything saying that the users of a view must also have access to the underlying tables.

Comment: How is the database link defined?  Are you connecting to the remote database as a fixed user or (my guess) as the current user?  If you are connecting as the current user, the error makes sense-- `user2` doesn't have access to the underlying table in database B and creating a view on database A can't change that fact.

Comment: It is a public database link so all users on database A who also have accounts on database B can use it. Are you suggesting that if I used a private database link (fixed to my user & password) then we wouldn't have this issue?

Comment: A public database link can be defined to connect to the remote database using a fixed username/ password.  Or it can be defined to connect to the remote database as the current user.  If you connect as a fixed user, queries over the database link use the permissions granted to that fixed user in the remote database.  If you connect as the current user, queries over the database link use the permissions granted to the current user in the remote database.  My guess is that you defined the public database link to connect as the current user rather than as a fixed user.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a public link that was set up well before my time, but as far as I can tell it is not linked to any particular user.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing MYVIEW1 into a materialized view (easier in our case than creating a private DB link).